# mutate data frame if duplicate found

Tags: r

I have a data frame and i am trying to mutate a new column and give 1,0 to duplicate found. for example i have data frame like below.

```
df4 <- data.frame(emp_id =c("DEV-2962","KTN_2252","ANA2719","ITI_2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","DEV2698","ITI2535","DEV2698","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@abcd.com","rahul.singh@abcd.com","salman.abbas@abcd.com","ram.lal@abcd.com","ram.lal@xyz.com","prabal.garg@xyz.com","sanu.ali@abcd.com","kunal.singh@abcd.com","lakhan.tomar@abcd.com","praveen.thakur@abcd.com","sarman.ali@abcd.com","zuber.khan@dkl.com","giriraj.singh@dkl.com","lokesh.sharma@abcd.com","pooja.pawar@abcd.com","nikita.sharma@abcd.com"))
```

now I am mutating a new column for highlight duplicates.

```
EMP_ID = "emp_id"

df4 <- df4 %>% group_by(!!EMP_ID) %>%
  mutate(`Duplicate_id` = ifelse(duplicated(df4[[!!EMP_ID]])==TRUE,"00. id duplicated",""))
```

its Creating a unnecessary new column with name "empid" but the output should be like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> df4 %>% group_by(!!sym(EMP_ID)) %>%
+   mutate(`Duplicate_id` = ifelse(duplicated(!!sym(EMP_ID)),"00. id duplicated",''))
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   emp_id [14]
   emp_id   email                   Duplicate_id     
   <fct>    <fct>                   <chr>            
 1 DEV-2962 akash.dev@abcd.com      ""               
 2 KTN_2252 rahul.singh@abcd.com    ""               
 3 ANA2719  salman.abbas@abcd.com   ""               
 4 ITI_2624 ram.lal@abcd.com        ""               
 5 DEV2698  ram.lal@xyz.com         ""               
 6 HRT2921  prabal.garg@xyz.com     ""               
 7 ""       sanu.ali@abcd.com       ""               
 8 KTN2624  kunal.singh@abcd.com    ""               
 9 DEV2698  lakhan.tomar@abcd.com   00. id duplicated
10 ITI2535  praveen.thakur@abcd.com ""               
11 DEV2698  sarman.ali@abcd.com     00. id duplicated
12 HRT2837  zuber.khan@dkl.com      ""               
13 ERV2951  giriraj.singh@dkl.com   ""               
14 KTN2542  lokesh.sharma@abcd.com  ""               
15 ANA2813  pooja.pawar@abcd.com    ""               
16 ITI2210  nikita.sharma@abcd.com  ""               
>
```

Comment: i have just updated my code , i am giving a user input parameters to give the name of column and that i am recalling in my code.

Comment: @newcomer, have updated my answer, please check if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need the dplyr::group_by.

```
library(dplyr)

EMP_ID <- "emp_id"

df4 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(`Duplicate_id` = ifelse(duplicated(!!sym(EMP_ID)),"00. id duplicated",''))
```

You can use group_by if your want to find duplicates in groups of the table (example would be to group by the "email" column and then look for duplicated "emp_id" or vice-versa)